# Include file in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, include, response.write

I have an include file "menu.inc" that I would like to store in the Style Library folder.

Is there a way to include this file in my masterpage from inside Sharepoint? Response.Write doesn't seem to work because it requires a physical path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the following code:

```
string htmlUri = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url.ToString() + "/Style%20Library/menu/menu.inc";

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(htmlUri);
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

WebResponse responseHtml = req.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(responseHtml.GetResponseStream()))
{
    tdMenu.InnerHtml = r.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WebRequest object to open the file into a StreamReader then render the contents of the file out using Response.Write.

Comment: I'm now getting the following error message when running the line: WebResponse responseHtml = requestHtml.GetResponse();

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Any ideas?